# FileMaker 14 Pro Two Tables One Date Range

Tags: filemaker

I have two tables. The first, table A, has dates, unique codes and costs. The second, table B, has dates, unique codes and revenues. Table A = >> Table B (One to Many Relationship). Now what I'm having difficulty with is running a find that gives me all the Costs in Table A and all the revenues in Table B for a specific period. The goal is to be able to calculate the cash basis for the period which is just cost + revenue for the period.

This seems like it should be a simple problem, but every time I run a find on Table B list layout, it does give me all revenue from Jan 1 to Jan 15 but if the related cost occurs before Jan 1 then it includes those two and they shouldn't be accounted for in the formula. Also if there are costs that occur between Jan 1 and Jan 15, even if there is no revenue in Table B that occurs between that period they should be included.

So I'm pretty lost at how to do this without running two finds on two tables to get the correct number then manually adding them together.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say I fully understood your description of the two tables. It sounds like you want to do a search in the child (Revenues?) table for records where **both** the date **and** the parent (Costs?) date are within the required range?